# How do you correctly format multiple columns of integers in python?

Tags: python

I have some code here:

```
for i in range(self.size):
    print('{:6d}'.format(self.data[i], end=' '))
        if (i + 1) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0:
            print()
```

Right now this prints as:

`1
1
1
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
(whitespace)
3
3
3
etc.`

It creates a new line when it hits 10 digits, but it doens't print the initial 10 in a row...

This is what I want-

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3
3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5
```

However when it hits two digit numbers it gets messed up -

```
8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 10
10 10 10 10 10 10 etc.
```

I want it to be right-aligned like this-

```
  8  8  8  8  8  9
 10 10 10 10 11 12 etc.
```

When I remove the format piece it will print the rows out, but there wont be the extra spacing in there of course!

Comment: Don't post images. They can't be searched or read with screen readers and the text can't be copied.  Use four spaces at the beginning of lines to format them as code and keep your line spacing.  You can highlight a block of lines and press the `{}` button or hit ctrl-K to add four spaces as well.

Comment: Try and ensure you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align strings by "padding" values using a string's [`.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rjust#str.rjust) method. Using some dummy data:

```
NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 10
for i in range(100):
    print("{}".format(i//2).rjust(3), end=' ')
    #print("{:3}".format(i//2), end=' ') edit: this also works. Thanks AChampion
    if (i + 1) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0:
        print()

#Output:
  0   0   1   1   2   2   3   3   4   4 
  5   5   6   6   7   7   8   8   9   9 
 10  10  11  11  12  12  13  13  14  14 
 15  15  16  16  17  17  18  18  19  19 
 20  20  21  21  22  22  23  23  24  24 
 25  25  26  26  27  27  28  28  29  29 
 30  30  31  31  32  32  33  33  34  34 
 35  35  36  36  37  37  38  38  39  39 
 40  40  41  41  42  42  43  43  44  44 
 45  45  46  46  47  47  48  48  49  49
```

Comment: This can be simplified a little, if you are going to use format then you don't need `rjust()`, e.g.: `print("{:3}".format(i//2), end=' ')`

Comment: Alternatively, if you are going to use `rjust()` then you just need `str()`, e.g. `str(i//2).rjust(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to just chunk up the data into rows and print each row, e.g.:

```
def chunk(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

for row in chunk(self.data, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS):
    print(' '.join(str(data).rjust(6) for data in row))
```

e.g:

```
In []:
for row in chunk(range(100), 10):
    print(' '.join(str(data//2).rjust(3) for data in row))

Out[]:
  0   0   1   1   2   2   3   3   4   4
  5   5   6   6   7   7   8   8   9   9
 10  10  11  11  12  12  13  13  14  14
 15  15  16  16  17  17  18  18  19  19
 20  20  21  21  22  22  23  23  24  24
 25  25  26  26  27  27  28  28  29  29
 30  30  31  31  32  32  33  33  34  34
 35  35  36  36  37  37  38  38  39  39
 40  40  41  41  42  42  43  43  44  44
 45  45  46  46  47  47  48  48  49  49
```

Comment: Thank you so much!